# So this script is making over 3000 API call per hour and I have no idea why.How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

So I'm trying to get the sub count of a Youtube channel using their API every 5 seconds, but instead it's making over 3000 call per hour which makes me reach the calls cap in 3 hours. I'm trying to understand why it's acting that way

For now I have checked for a forkbomb as well as put console log to see what's happening but to no avail.

```
function run() {
    setInterval(updateProgressBar, 5000);
}

function updateProgressBar() {
var collectedData = JSON.parse(
    fetchChannelData(
    "here's lie the private key I won't share"
    )
);

//other not important code
}

function fetchChannelData(requestUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", requestUrl, false); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

I'm expecting the API to register a call every 5 seconds, but now it's one every 0.9 seconds

Comment: OP you might want to anonymise your google api's key or someone can bombard your api.

Comment: Where do you call `run()`?

Comment: run is called when the page is open Mark

Comment: How many pages did you open?

Comment: Please show the code that calls `run`.  I suspect its getting called multiple times.

Comment: if you are worried about API call caps I am not sure I would place this call in the client code. You should make this call from your server updating the data server side and sending that info down to the client so that each client that opens your site isn't making this call every 5 seconds.

Comment: synchronous requests are a bad idea. Making Ajax calls with setInterval is also not a great idea.